# jScrollPane height refresh based on my content (not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jscrollpane

I'm using the [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) plug-in along with my SmartAutocomplete (https://github.com/laktek/jQuery-Smart-Auto-Complete) and i'm appending the Autocomplete results into my main containing div for jScrollPane so the user can scroll through them.

This works, but my problems is when a new set of data is appended to my jScrollPane the height (scroll area) does not update, it always stays the same height.. so items are either cut off or there is a large amount of white space at the bottom.

I've looked at the demo for their dynamic content example but can't get this to work: [Demo here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The property you are looking for is the autoreinitialize property. You need to call something like:

```
$('#idofyourcontainer').jScrollPane({ autoReinitialise: true });
```

when changes are being made to your container.